# Decoding base64 encoded message with a key

Tags: hash, databases, encoding

I am pentesting a database that where I found data which was `base64` encoded. I tried the usual method of decoding `base64`, which didn't work.

Later, I found in database a field called `base64_custom_key`. How do I decrypt a `base64` encoded message with a key?

Comment: Have you tried to treat the decoded data as AES data and the decoded key as AES key? How long is the decoded key?

Comment: The base64_custom_key is 64 characters long. The decoded data doesn't make sense (it gives out weird symbols and unicode characters)

Comment: I tried decoding it as AES256 (since the output was 64 chars), and it says "bad magic number".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base-n systems have n different symbols in their alphabet. Base 2 is just ones and zeros, base 10 has 0 through 9. Base 64 has 64 unique characters, as defined in its RFC.

If you see a 64-character long `base64_custom_key` field, I would guess that's the alphabet you have to use. I'll do an example.

The normal alphabet is A-Z, a-z, 0-9, `+` and `,`. If the `base64_custom_key` contains `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+,` then you have to do nothing because that's the original. But because the original does not decode properly, I guess that's not it.

If `base64_custom_key` contains `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123459876+,` (everything normal, except the `9876` part), you might have to replace 9 with 6, 8 with 7, 7 with 8 and 6 with 9, and then run the decoder. The base64 encoding of `zzz` is `enp6`, but with this custom key it would be `enp9`. To decode it, we need to replace the 9 with a 6 as described, and you can then decode that normally.

Does that make sense?

It might not work, I'm just guessing what this might mean and how you might need to use that custom field. It's certainly non-standard and not a secure system, if it was intended for encryption at all (though I can't imagine another purpose).

Comment: In earlier comments you said the field was 64 characters long but this is 134 characters long, which is not even divisible by 64. I can't really tell you what you're supposed to do with this...

Comment: I liked your idea, thought that would be the case and wrote a script to map the characters. the output was '+Trm9e46wgffiJMfPeuMygLKPTj0' , which again won't decode as base64 @Luc

Comment: There are several base64 alphabets -- two standardized in http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648, uuencode ASCII SP to _, and more niche and proprietary ones -- but the most common by far is MIME-and-HTTP, based on PEM, which is A-Za-z0-9+/ (**slash not comma**) and = for padding. That said, while I can easily imagine an app using *a* nonstandard alphabet, it makes no sense to use a different alphabet for each database row: it takes space (and I/O) and more complicated processing for no benefit.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 It seems the database uses the same key for all rows. (Yes, it does look like nonstandard thing)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Yeah I can't imagine what they were thinking to design this either, but a custom alphabet would be implemented in code, not stored in the database I'd think, so this would have to be for encryption... then again, abhi_kaffe just mentioned each row is the same, so perhaps they really did just want to use a custom alphabet for some reason.